# Не подгружается шрифт в изолированном HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Создал на Реакте приложение, которое забирает данные с инпутов, вставляет их в разметку и сохраняет эту разметку в HTML файлик, и беда в том, что этот файлик используется как подпись в Outlook. Соответственно плевать он хотел на шрифт, который я подключил к файлу. Пробовал Google fonts через ссылку, пробовал путем добавления класса, вписывал напрямую в стили. Не помогает...

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58937013/3129992) не читали?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook  использует свои стили... Их наверное переопределить можно только в программе:

[Ссылка](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-outlook-20f72414-2c42-4b53-9654-d07a92b9294a)

Comment: Вообще он подтягивает и использует шрифт. Однако у пользователя, кому будет отправлена подпись шрифта не будет, и будет использоваться альтернативный "веб-безопасный". И вот соль в том, что я не знаю как принудительно загружать шрифт пользователю на устройство. Был бы просто стандартный html - проблем меньше, но там JSX((

Comment: Не очень хорошая практика, принудительно загружать пользователю нечто, что он не заказывал.